# Why is R making my CSV files larger?

Tags: r, csv

I am attempting to read in a series of CSV files and prepare them for later appending. Before I append them, I need to create a column that tells me what original file they came from. In this case, they are divisions of a business. I am currently using a number code to reduce the amount of the file size increase.

I am getting large jumps in the file size from the read CSVs to the written ones. Without adding the "divisions" column (commented out below), my file sizes are increasing as follows:

19,111 KB to 24,458 KB; 71,331 KB to 89,989 KB; 33,919 KB to 42,898 KB

Can anyone explain? Is there a way to improve the code?

Thanks!

```
insert.division <- function(fileroot, divisionname){

    ext <- ".csv"
    file <- paste(fileroot, ext, sep = "")
    data <- read.csv(file, header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    #data$division <- divisionname
    write.csv(data, file = paste(fileroot, "_adj3", ext, sep = ""),
        row.names = FALSE)

}

files <- c(
    "file1",
    "file2",
    "file3",
    "file4",
    "file5"
)

divisions <- c(1:5)

mapply(insert.division, fileroot = files, divisionname = divisions)
```

Comment: Compare input and output files with a text editor. I have some ideas, but there is no reproducible example here.

Comment: @Roland: Thanks for the suggestion. It seems to be a matter of the addition of double quotes around all strings and also addition of NA's. Any way to fix this? Or maybe it won't affect performance when I merge the CSVs?

Answer (score 0):

The reason seems to be that write.csv is adding quotes around all the strings, whereas Excel only used them for strings that contained a comma. More info: 
[Delete "" from csv values and change column names when writing to a CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11222773/how-to-delete-from-csv-values-in-r-and-how-to-change-column-names-when-writin)