# generate .txt without "" and the rownames

Tags: r, text

I am trying to generate a pheno.txt file, which only contains three columns. I used the following code:

```
> pheno <- data.frame(fid, id, pht)
> head(pheno)
  fid   id pht
1   1  id4   1
2   2 id10   1
3   3 id25   1
4   4 id33   1
5   5 id35   1
6   6 id58   1
```

> write.table(pheno, "/home/local/Documents/pheno.txt", sep ="\t" )

However, the pheno.txt looks like below:

```
"fid"   "id"    "pht"
"1" 1   "id4"   1
"2" 2   "id10"  1
"3" 3   "id25"  1
"4" 4   "id33"  1
"5" 5   "id35"  1
"6" 6   "id58"  1
"7" 7   "id68"  1
```

Could anyone can tell me, how to remove all "" and the row names in this file? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use arguments `row.names = FALSE` and `quote = FALSE`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete "" from csv values and change column names when writing to a CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11222773/delete-from-csv-values-and-change-column-names-when-writing-to-a-csv)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `help(write.table)`:

> quote: a logical value (‘TRUE’ or ‘FALSE’) or a numeric vector.  If
>             ‘TRUE’, any character or factor columns will be surrounded by
>             double quotes.
>
> row.names: either a logical value indicating whether the row names of
>             ‘x’ are to be written along with ‘x’

So, this should do the trick:

```
write.table(pheno, "/home/local/Documents/pheno.txt", 
            sep ="\t", quote=FALSE, row.names=FALSE )
```